# Content expands beyond its column container

Tags: plugins, widgets, css

everyone!

I was wondering if anyone would be able to tell me how the content in my center column is able to expand its allowed container size and push my right column/widget area to the bottom?

Here's a link to the page where I'm having this problem: https://goo.gl/XFnmnD

Here's a screenshot to show exactly where on the page the problem is: http://snag.gy/3A0Sg.jpg.

This only happens with the plugin I'm using. I tried practically changing every container width % to 96%, which didn't work. The problem only happens when the user is logged out. When the user logs in, everything fits fine. If I remove the plugin and put something else there, there's no problem either. Any ideas?

Thanks!

P.S. I just joined today, so go easy on me, please.

Comment: Oops. "Hey, everyone!" It won't let me save my edit. :(

Comment: "This only happens with the plugin I'm using" which plugin is it, and have you tried their support forums?

Comment: Yeah, but they said they'd look into it, but it's been a few days already and I posted something else on their forum, but no response. This plugin doesn't have much activity going on just yet

Comment: The problem is in their code. Nothing we can do here without knowing what that is.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. So we found out the first problem which is that the plugin placed in its middle column/container is making the container on the right its child/sub container. Any idea on what I should look for to change that?

Comment: I need to see code, sorry. Output means nothing without knowing the logic.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the most right column is being nested within the middle reviews column.

I imagine that somewhere in the code (template, sidebar, or widget) there is a conditional statement causing your middle column to not get closed off before the right column starts.

To illustrate what is happening, this is how it currently gets rendered:

```
<div class="fl-col fl-col-small fl-node-569586b0f1e9e" style="width: 39.94%;" data-node="569586b0f1e9e">
    ...middle column content...

    <div class="fl-col fl-col-small fl-node-569586b0f1ee5" style="width: 20.02%;" data-node="569586b0f1ee5">
    ...right column content...
    </div>
</div>
```

But what it should be:

```
<div class="fl-col fl-col-small fl-node-569586b0f1e9e" style="width: 39.94%;" data-node="569586b0f1e9e">
    ...middle column content...
</div>
<div class="fl-col fl-col-small fl-node-569586b0f1ee5" style="width: 20.02%;" data-node="569586b0f1ee5">
    ...right column content...
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

So that was a wonderful idea! I decided to inspect the HTML elements and removed the pieces of code that had a matching pair. I realized they all had a matching pair; however, for some reason, the second column's container was enveloping the third column's container to make it a sub-container if that makes sense?

Here's the code snippet I managed to parse out:

http://snag.gy/oDJB4.jpg

It's a screenshot since I can't figure out how to select the whole selection and and copy and paste. I put red square brackets to show the third container's location.

So thanks for helping solve the first problem. I guess the second now is: Does anyone know what code I should look for to figure out how the second container/plugin I'm using is making the third container a child container?

Thanks again, everyone!

Comment: Please, this is a Q&A site and not a forum, answers should be to the point, and there is no reason to include your life story, no one that will come here searching for a fix to similar problem will be intrested in it. "The HTML was broken and I fixed it" would have been good enough. This is also not the place to extend the question, you should either edit your question or ask a new one.